# What will be an efficient way to retrieve info OnKeyUp search from a web page?

Tags: design, search

I am very new to the software industry. I was assigned to implement `keyup search` or `real time search` for a web page. I need to search `employee code`.

For example, employee code is like `TM-00001`. If user types `T` then search box will show all the employee codes with prefix `T`. This is very basic and I can do this by using AJAX and select with a `Like` operator. But the database is large. We are using `Oracle` database.

What will be an efficient way to do the search?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is for a user interface, you don't need to return all the records.

Limit the query to the top 51 records that match the search criteria.  If you actually get 51 records back to the interface, replace the last one with some indicator ("...") to show that more records are available and the user should keep typing.

Something else to try - don't even attempt the search until you have some minimum number of characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the meantime I did some googling. Many of them are referring Apache Solr. Is it overwhelming for this simple search ?

Comment: @seal: Apache Solr is a full enterprise search platform. You feed it information, it indexes it, you do searches that query those indexes for fast results. You can optimize your search for employee code in more lightweight ways, so if this is the only use case you have, then Solr might be too much.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add one thing to Dan Pichelman's answer. When the user starts typing display a spinner or some indicator that a search is underway but don't actually make the call to the server.

**Instead, you should [debounce](https://john-dugan.com/javascript-debounce/) the function call.** If user types very fast you will make unnecessary calls to the database. But if you debounce the call you will make one call when the input settles.

There are various utils that can help you with that. And just for completeness sake, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function) too.